# swagger formData validation not working

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

It seems like the swagger validator for `"type":"file"` is not working.

```
{
    "name": "receipt",
    "in": "formData",
    "required": true,
    "type": "file"
}
```

If I use `"required": false` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.
If I use `"requried": true` I get `ValidationError: "receipt" is required`

I get the error with `curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --form "receipt=@myimage.jpg"  "http://localhost:8000/insights"`
And when using `swagger-ui`.

The error must be in the validation since uploading files without specifying it is swagger works just fine. Also the validation for `"in":"query"` works just fine.

Workaround I would be happy with: Disabling the validation, so I can use the documentation function of swagger.